# How to separate a two digit hexadecimal number into its digits?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a hexadecimal number `4e`. How to get `4` and `e` separately and store it in two separate variables?

Comment: Where do you have the `4e` is it in a `std::string`?

Comment: `"4e"[0]` is `'e'`; `"4e"[1]` is `'4'`. Keep in mind that hexadecimal describes a **text representation** of a value.

Comment: You need to clarify what you are trying to do.  There is no indication how you have the `4e` represented, whether it is a `std::string` or an integer.  Then the mystery of these two "separate variables" -- we don't know if they will be integers, strings, a single character, ...

Comment: *from a hex-dump, its stored in a uint8_t pointer* -- What does a hex dump have to do with pointers?  Totally confused.

Comment: @Koushik -- it's stored in memory that a `uint8_t` pointer points at. It's not stored in a pointer.

Comment: I think the answer covers uint8_t .

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry for not being clear. I am acquiring data from a detector through sockets which is in the form of hex, like `8c 4a 2f 9e ...`. Basically I need to split the byte into nibbles, like `8` and `c`.

Comment: @Koushik -- What do you mean by "in the form of hex"?  There is no "form of hex", unless those are strings representing hexadecimal values.  The "form" you are seeing is only what your viewer/debugger/editor, or whatever you are viewing the data with is showing you.  Those values could just as well be base 10, `140 74 47 158...`

Comment: @Koushik -- As a real world example, there is a format called "HexEncoding", where a file encoded in this way is basically one big string of hex bytes, each two bytes representing an 8 bit character.  For example: "41424330" would be, once it's decoded, "ABC0" (assuming ASCII).  So unless the data is coming in as a hex encoded string, what you are attempting to describe is your viewer's choice of showing you the data in hex, and not an actual hex string that you are receiving.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for elaborating on that. Cleared out many things!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you mean 'how can I get the upper and lower nibbles of a byte into two variables'

```
 char x = 0x4e;
 int low = x & 0x0f;
 int high = (x & 0xf0) >> 4;
```

Comment: For bit manipulation I would use unsigned char and unsigned int constants.